# Laravel 5: Use Redis PCEL extension

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5

I'm trying to use Redis as cache storage in Laravel 5. Predis is working fine, but the Redis PCEL extension is much faster.

What are the steps to use the Redis PCEL extension with L5?

[The only hint the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/redis) are giving me is to rename the alias, I did that, but I still get a "Class 'Predis\Client' not found" exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah.

Remove the `Redis` alias from `app.aliases` and register your own `RedisServiceProvider` in `app.providers`. I also added a custom `RedisDatabase`.

https://gist.github.com/tillkruss/27eda66e77280f1ba727